# Customizing BuddyPress registration form template, not just registar.php

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I know that general modifications can be made to register.php, but it still does not provide direct access to the inputs or labels in any meaningful way. I want to add additional blocks to better organize groups of fields. Currently using BP 3.2.0

Basically BP allows modification to the elements surrounding it.

For example (https://github.com/buddypress/BuddyPress/blob/master/src/bp-templates/bp-nouveau/buddypress/members/register.php):

```
        <div class="register-section default-profile" id="basic-details-section">

            <?php /***** Basic Account Details ******/ ?>

            <h2 class="bp-heading"><?php esc_html_e( 'Account Details', 'buddypress' ); ?></h2>

            <?php bp_nouveau_signup_form(); ?>

        </div><!-- #basic-details-section -->
```

**bp_nouveau_signup_form();** Gets called in template-tags.php: https://github.com/buddypress/BuddyPress/blob/master/src/bp-templates/bp-nouveau/includes/template-tags.php However, this file is a direct part of the plugin and can't be overwritten in the same manner as register.php

There doesn't appear to be a transparent and clean way modifying the form structure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you will have to modify that in the bp_nouveau_signup_form(); function. If you are using phpstorm, you can double tap shift and search all the project files for it.

it starts on line 2299 of the file you linked